# configure llvm fail. Host Clang must be able to find libstdcxx4.7 or newer

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm

my project depends on llvm+clang+cmake.I use ninja to make compile simple.
my OS is : OS X Yosemite(10.10.5).here is how the error occurs.

1) get llvm&clang

```
$ mkdir ~/clang-llvm && cd ~/clang-llvm
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git
$ cd llvm/tools
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
$ cd clang/tools
$ git clone http://llvm.org/git/clang-tools-extra.git extra
```

2) install CMake and  Ninja

```
$ cd ~/clang-llvm
$ git clone https://github.com/martine/ninja.git
$ cd ninja
$ git checkout release
$ ./bootstrap.py
$ sudo cp ninja /usr/bin/

$ cd ~/clang-llvm
$ git clone git://cmake.org/stage/cmake.git
$ cd cmake
$ git checkout next
$ ./bootstrap
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

3)compile ninja

```
$ cd ~/clang-llvm
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -G Ninja ../llvm -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON  # Enable tests; default is off.
$ ninja
$ ninja install
```

4)config clang

```
$ cd ~/clang-llvm/build
$ ccmake ../llvm
```

after that , I get into the advanced mode (by press t)

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER：*I change it to  clang++*
CMAKE_C_COMPILER：*I change it to  clang*
LLVM_ENABLE_EH and  LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI： *I change it from OFF to ON*
```

and then I press c to configure. error happens.ERROR is :

```
**CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:43 (message):
   Host Clang must be able to find libstdc++4.7 or newer!
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMakeLists.txt:358 (include)**
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: a) Your question is unrelated to ninja, please remove the tag. b) Your title suggests you have a problem configuring CMake 3.4. This is not the case, you get the error when you configure LLVM. c) Your forth point is "configure llvm" and not CMake. d) Please put additional information like your OS into the question by adding it, don't add these informations by commens. e) Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @usr1234567 thank you for your advice. BTW, configure llvm error, can u  help me out ? thx.

Comment: Have you libstdc++4.7 or newer installed? What about libc++? Maybe just the -devel package is missing. Post more of the cmake run, please.

Comment: I have installed gcc4.8 (port install gcc4.8) and still have the same error.  
more of the cmake run, do u mean the error log in CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log?

Comment: No, the output (standard out) CMake generates. The same where you get error message from.

Comment: @usr1234567 the problem has been solved. I downloaded libcxx of llvm and put it into llvm/projects. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Would you mind to delete your question?

Comment: @usr1234567 - If he did, I would still be searching for the solution to this.